# Deserializing Web Json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize the json string to objects and then write it to a richtextbox

```
 public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://opskins.com/api/user_api.php?request=GetOP&key=16a70bbdbcbae2e1574c18a5746046");

            var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);

            richTextBox1.Text = jarray.op;


        }
    }
```

Class:

```
public class Result
{
    public string op { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know api key doesnt exist because I changed it, but how do I deserialize other things? I looked it up and all the solutions didn't work for me and I have been confused for days.

Comment: So, what is your problem?  If you are getting an exception, what is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception?  What does the JSON look like?  Since you've (hopefully) changed the API key we have no way to reproduce your problem (or even know what it is) from what you have told us.  See [ask].

Comment: Can tell us what value you are getting in `json` variable?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm just getting the string it shows on the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mapping the object properly.

Your issue is because you are not mapping the JSON object properly to your `Result` class.

*If we use your current link https://opskins.com/api/user_api.php?request=GetOP&key=foo*

The object we get returned back in JSON is like this:

```
{
    "result": {
        "code": 401,
        "error": "API key does not exist"
    }
}
```

Which would mean the class you would map it to would look like this

```
public class Result
{
    public int Code { get; set; }  // note this is an int
    public string Error{ get; set; }
}
```

---

### Mapping the object properly (to your textbox).

In the event that you want to map it to your text box.

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://your-uri-goes-here");
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);

    richTextBox1.Text = data.Error; // this will work because Error is of type string
}
```

> **Note that there is an `@` in front of the URI string.** As API keys may likely contain special characters that make need to be escaped.

If you wish to map a `Type` that is not a `string`, make sure you do a conversion for it, in some cases `.ToString()` will be sufficient.

Comment: I get an unhandled exception error when I map the class like that and try to write to textbox, (401) Unauthorized

Comment: Im still getting the Unauthorized exception error when I startup.                                   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: @DylanBro did you place the `@` in front of your URI string?